# Proof of relation between Betti numbers of base manifold and its covering space

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, covering-spaces

For a  covering $p\colon\widetilde{M}\to M$ with compact $\widetilde{M}$, how to show that $b_i(M)\leq b_i(\widetilde{M})$ for $0<i<n=\dim(M)$.

If I understand this inequality correctly it says that every generator of $i$-th **co**homology of $M$ is also a generator for $i$-th **co**homology of $\widetilde{M}$. I am looking for a simple *differential geometric* proof using De Rham cohomology and a sketch using algebraic topology methods of this fact?

Here is a related post: [Betti numbers of the orientable double cover is same as non-orientable one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4168057/272127)

Comment: But $\tilde{M}$ is not compact!!

Comment: @Mindlack: What do you meant? So the compactness assumption is for $M$?

Comment: I was referring to an earlier comment, now deleted, pointing out the case $M=S^1$, $\tilde{M}=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I take it you're assuming a good deal about the space $M$ (e.g., that it has a rich enough structure to support differential forms). You might want to explicitly characterize what you're assuming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a natural pushforward $p_*$ of differential forms from those on $\tilde{M}$ to those on $M$. The definition is local, so to see what it looks like take a small open subset trivializing the covering map.

What is interesting is that $p_*$ commutes with the exterior derivative $d$, so that it induces a cohomology morphism $H^*(\tilde{M}) \rightarrow H^*(M)$. But then, you can see that $p_*p^*$ is a scalar map on differential forms, so that $p_*$ is surjective in cohomology, which concludes.

Comment: Sorry by that inequality, one can conclude that the covering space is NOT simpler than the base. This is a little strange to me as I always thought the converse.

Comment: @C.F.G Relative to your comment, if you have a $2$-holed torus, for example, what genus surfaces will be a covering space of it?

Comment: @TedShifrin: I think in general $0, 2, 4, \dots $. e.g. $\Bbb R^2$ the $2$-holed torus itself, $4$-holed torus.

Comment: @C.F.G In fact, won’t every $g$-holed torus with $g\ge 2$? My point was that their topology is “more complicated,” not less. You’re wrong about $g<2$. Figure out why.

Comment: @TedShifrin: a $3$-holed torus will? Am I correct: by winding one handle twice and identity over the other handle is a 3-fold covering. Yeah? I told $\Bbb R^2$ because a $2$-holed torus is a quotient of it. Also a _universal cover_ is not simpler than $2$-holed torus. it is?